# Winning strategy of Peter such that quadratic equations has Rational roots

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

Peter picked three non zero ***real*** numbers $a,b,c$  and Alan arranges these numbers as coefficients of Quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Peter wins if this Quadratic has distinct Rational roots, else Alan wins.

How can we prove that Peter always has winning strategy.

Since $a,b,c$ are non zero reals we have roots of quadratic as

$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Now Peter can win game only if $$b^2-4ac=k^2$$ where $k$ is Integer. But even though $b^2-4ac=k^2$ is integer, how can we say roots are rational?

Comment: Just a minor change. The quadratic looks more familiar if we use the first three letters of the alphabet.

Comment: why do you think peter does have a winning strategy?

Comment: its given in the book that Peter always has winning strategy

Comment: It might be.  But peter must chose them so that then largest absolute middle value are different parity.

Comment: ya i also thought of it thats why i have posted here

Comment: Logically what i thought is since peter is picking the numbers $a$,$b$,$c$ he will pick in such a way that all the six quadratic equations will have rational roots, but i am trying for those three numbers which gives rational roots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's enough to find one set of real numbers that Peter can choose to win. For example, $\{1, 2, -3\}$ will work. We can check that:
\begin{align}
  x^2 + 2x - 3 &= (x+3)(x-1) \\
  x^2 - 3x + 2 &= (x-2)(x-1) \\
  2x^2 + x - 3 &= (2x+3)(x-1) \\
  2x^2 - 3x + 1 &= (2x-1)(x-1) \\
  -3x^2 + x + 2 &= -(3x+2)(x-1) \\
  -3x^2 + 2x + 1 &= -(3x+1)(x-1)
\end{align}
and so both roots of all six polynomials Alan can form are rational and distinct.

---

I found this by brute force, but in retrospect it seems obvious why this worked and how we can find lots more such triples. Since $1+2+(-3)=0$, $x=1$ will always be a root of the quadratic equation, and factoring out $x-1$ must produce a second rational root.

Comment: How did you find that?  Did you just guess?

Comment: Awesome this is what i am trying for, thanks a lot

Comment: No, I had Mathematica guess for me. I tried a bunch of triples of integers checking if each of $a^2-4bc$, $b^2-4ac$, and $c^2-4ab$ were integers, and found this as the simplest.

Comment: But now I've realized why this triple worked, and it's for an embarrassingly simple reason, which I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Misha Lavrov, ${1,2,-3}$ is a solution. But that's not the only case. In fact, Peter can choose any three integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that they sum up to zero i.e. $a+b+c=0$.

Proof:
For the equation to have rational roots, the discriminant should be a perfect square. If $a+b+c=0$, then $b=-(a+c)$. Thus, the discriminant $D$ becomes $(a+c)^2-4ac=(a-c)^2$, which is clearly a perfect square. This method is general i.e. you can switch any of $a$, $b$ and $c$, always resulting in a perfect square discriminant.

Hope this helps :)